# My hard drive can only boot once every two times

Tags: ubuntu, bios, boot

I just installed a Kingston 64 GB SSD into my laptop, replacing the old 80 GB 5400 RPM one. The drive starts up and works fine *every other* time. For example, if I'm running normally, and press "Restart", I get:

```
2100 Initialization error on HDD0.
```

I turn off the computer manually, restart, and...it boots into Ubuntu again. This happens *every other* time without fail...anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Are you running the latest firmware on the SSD and the latest BIOS on the notebook?

Comment: Have you checked with Kingston?  You paid extra for a Kingston device you may as well benefit from their support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have updated to the latest firmware, and as is advised by most tech websites, set your bios to AHCI mode (which will need new drivers for).

To do this, restart your computer, and press the key to enter setup (usually DEL, but can vary. Watch the boot screen for it). Afterwards, look under Advanced Bios settings, or something to that effect, where you should find 'IDE mode' or something similar. Change it to AHCI mode, and save changes. If you can't boot, switch back into IDE mode, and download AHCI drivers. There are guides for installing the drivers about the web, like [Here](http://forum.msi.com.tw/index.php?topic=106575.0) and [Here](http://gianvito.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/how-to-install-ahci-drivers-even-if-youve-installed-vistaxp-in-ide-mode/). With any hope, that should fix your problem. My SSD used to do this, until I updated firmware and switched to AHCI mode (not sure which of the two fixed it).